# Get accurate value onChange event in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange

I'm trying to get the value of the date onChange:

```
<Flatpickr
   data-enable-time
   name="goodsreadyby"
     options={{
       minDate: date,
       enableTime: true,
       dateFormat:
        'Y-m-d H:i:s'
       }}
     onChange={(date) => {setGoodsReadyBy({date})
     }}/>
```

My problem is that I'm getting Array onChange event.
Currently :

```
{date: Array(1)}
date: Array(1)
0: Sat Mar 05 2022 16:20:00  (Some Standard Time)
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

But I need the value like    `Sat Mar 05 2022 16:20:00  (Some Standard Time)` only. How did I modify my code to get the exact value that I needed.

Comment: What is the value of the 2nd param of `onChange`?

Comment: the default value is current date `new Date()` and onChange I'm getting the Array with 1 object named date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st param of Flatpickr's `onChange` prop is `selectedDates` - an array of Dates (you can just access the first with `selectedDates[0]` and format it like you would with any Date).

The 2nd is the `dateStr` - as formatted by the `dateFormat` option.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Flatpickr
      data-enable-time
      name="goodsreadyby"
      options={{
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:s"
      }}
      onChange={(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
        const firstDate = selectedDates[0];
        console.log({ firstDate, dateStr });
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

> onChange will receive 3 arguments when called. These are:
>
> - `selectedDates` - an array of Date objects selected by the user. When there are no dates selected, the array is empty.
> - `dateStr` - a string representation of the latest selected Date object by the user. The string is formatted as per the dateFormat option.
> - `instance` - the flatpickr object, containing various methods and properties.

[Flatpickr docs](https://flatpickr.js.org/events/)

[image: Edit late-brook-45k242]

Comment: Still I'm getting Array , `{date: Array(1), currentDateString: '2022-03-05 16:49:0'}
currentDateString: "2022-03-05 16:49:0"
date: [Sat Mar 05 2022 16:49:00 GMT+0000 (Some Standard Time)]
[[Prototype]]: Object`

Comment: Yes `selectedDates` is an array, as per the docs. You can access the first date in the array with `selectedDates[0]`

Comment: Thanks modifying to `onChange={(dateStr) => {setGoodsReadyBy(dateStr)}}`  returning the value as i wanted .

Comment: Remember Flatpickr can be in "single", "multiple", or "range" `mode` which is why `selectedDates` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the date like,

```
goodsReadyBy?.date[0].toString()
```

Code to fetch the date string alone:

```
const App = () => {
  const [goodsReadyBy, setGoodsReadyBy] = useState();
  return (
    <div>
      <Flatpickr
        data-enable-time
        name="goodsreadyby"
        options={{
          enableTime: true,
          dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:s"
        }}
        onChange={(date) => {
          setGoodsReadyBy({ date });
        }}
      />
      <p> {goodsReadyBy?.date[0].toString()} </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Codesandbox:**

[image: Edit Example - React Hooks - useState (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

Well your array only has one element so you can use the code below.

```
 onChange={(date) => {setGoodsReadyBy({date[0]})
```

It will give you the data in the format you need.